# How to Split a String XML Column into no of rows based on the nodes present inside the XML Field

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have a `SQL` table in the below format with only one `XML` column:

```
[XML]

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<htmlString>
<MENUACTION v="Contact"/>
<MENUKEY/>
<PROGRAM v="SOWMENU03"/>
<HTMLFILE v="CGI/TEMP"/>
</htmlString>
```

I want to split this table row as follows based on the nodes inside

```
[Value_XML]                     [Control_ID]      [Data_Value]**

<MENUACTION v="Contact"/>       MENUACTION        Contact
<MENUKEY/>                      MENUKEY 
<PROGRAM v="SOWMENU03"/>        Program           SOWMENU03
<HTMLFILE v="CGI/TEMP"/>        HTMLFILE          CGI/TEMP
```

Note: The attribute value is mentioned using `V=`.Some times `V` will not be available for a node like `MENUKEY` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (you can replace the `NULL` value with empty string if you want):

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [Data] XML
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([Data])
SELECT '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <htmlString>
        <MENUACTION v="Contact"/>
        <MENUKEY/>
        <PROGRAM v="SOWMENU03"/>
        <HTMLFILE v="CGI/TEMP"/>
        </htmlString>'

SELECT T.c.query('.') AS [Value_XML]
      ,T.c.value('local-name(.)', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS [Control_ID] 
      ,T.c.value('(./@v)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS [Data_Value]
FROM @DataSource DS
CROSS APPLY [Data].nodes('/htmlString/*')  AS T(c)
```

[image]

Comment: You are correct GOTQN. But since my table has lakhs of record my query is running for a long time. It has much performance issues. Is there any other way of dealing this ?